# Search Excel columns for string

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
------  -----   -------
ABC     3600    Title 1
DEF     3601    Title 2
ABC     3603    Title 3
GHI     3603    Title 4
ABC     3602    Title 5
JKL     3604    Title 6
```

etc.

I need to say something like: IF Column A is 'ABC' and Column B is NOT(3601,3602,3603,3700) then put a '1' in Column D (an empty column).

How exactly do I put that in VBA?

Comment: I was trying each iteration: if ABC and 3601; if ABC and 3602; if ABC and 3602, etc. I was hoping to do as much as I could at one time.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this can be done with built-in formulas without recourse to VBA.

Comment: This is all part of a much larger macro, I was just trying to find a 'slick' way in VBA to do this. I understand what you're saying, though.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need VBA?

A formula would be:

```
=IF(A1="ABC";IF(OR(B1=3601;B1=3602;B1=3603;B1=3700);"";1);"")
```

There's an error (cells shifted) in a picture below, the formula above is correct.

[image]

VBA:

```
Function CellCombination(Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range) As String
  CellCombination = ""
    If Cell1.Value = "ABC" Then
      Select Case Cell2.Value
        Case 3601 To 3603, 3700
        Case Else
          CellCombination = "1"
      End Select
   End If
End Function
```

Spreadsheet with an example: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/CellCombinations.xls

Comment: Tried the 'formula', it only gave me FALSE for every record. When I try the VBA, it runs without an error but doesn't do anything.

Comment: At the start of the function you are returning the value so it never even gets to the If statement. You should add an "Exit Function" to the case else and move the first line to the bottom above End Function.

Comment: At the start of the function the value is set to `""`: we need output only in case `"ABC"` is detected. If not, the execution jumps directly to `End Function`. No `Exit Function` needed.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas: The VBA function switches its values between `""` and `"1"`. You can use it as a UDF (`=CellCombination(A1,B1)`) in `D1` or as a part of a Sub.